# Login & Password storage in databases

Tags: database, authentication, passwords, authorization

I am creating a simple chat and I want to add user login functionality.

I have a question: should I store logins and passwords (hash+salt) in the same database as messages and other chat stuff but in the distinct table or is there a better way to create another database for it?

Tell me how and why please. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the user table is part of the same database as you store other information. Important is, that it should contain only a salted hash of the password, this is not the same as en encrypted password. The salt must be stored as well, so you can reproduce the same hash when the user wants to login.

Password-hash functions will generate a string containing the password hash together with the random salt (should be different for each password). This string can be stored in the database. Appropriate password-hash functions are Argon2, BCrypt, SCrypt and PBKDF2, other hash functions like MD5, SHA* should not be used, because they are way too fast.

If you are looking for more information, have a look at my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

For me the salt is more an environment variable given to the hash function. But why  are you storing the salt ?

Answer (score 0):

**should I store logins and passwords (hash+salt) in the same database as messages and other chat stuff but in the distinct table?**

Yes, if they are in the same database, they MUST be in another table, such as "user". So you would have a table named users and one named message, for example.
The password must by encrypted as any other sensitive data that You have.
For example: are the messages private? Likely. So they better off encrypted. You don't want somebody with database access reading all the chat.

**Or is there a better way to create another database for it?**

If your system architecture is microservice, then there is a good chance that your login/user data should be in another database. It will imply data repetition, but easier to be maintain. However, it really depends on your system design. For very small app, I would not use microservices, unless You expect the app to grow at some point, new functionalities..etc.